# Dependency Property - Updating the source

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am driving crazy with a custom Dependency Property. I already checked loads of threads here, but haven't found any solution yet. What I want to do is to replace the value of the Property if the source provides a specific value (null for the given example). No matter what I try, the property value within the source remains null and is never updated.

Here is my Custom Control:

```
public class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{
    public TextBoxEx()
    {
        TrueValue = 0;
        this.TextChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            TrueValue = Text.Length;
            SetCurrentValue(MyPropertyProperty, TrueValue);
            var x = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, MyPropertyProperty);
            if (x != null)
            {
                x.UpdateSource();
            }
        };
    }

    public int? TrueValue { get; set; }

    public int? MyProperty
    {
        get { return (int?)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int?), typeof(TextBoxEx), new PropertyMetadata(null, PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue == null)
        {
            d.SetCurrentValue(MyPropertyProperty, (d as TextBoxEx).TrueValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the DataContext i am Binding:

```
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int? _Bar = null;

    public int? Bar
    {
        get { return _Bar; }
        set
        {
            _Bar = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Bar");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

My Binding looks like this:

```
<local:TextBoxEx MyProperty="{Binding Bar, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Remember: I need a TwoWay binding, so OneWayToSource does not work for me.

Any idea what I am not getting in here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to set the binding to two-way and it will work. But as that should be the default you can register the property accordingly using the following metadata:

```
... new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                                  FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                                  PropertyChangedCallback)
```

Getting the expression in the `TextChanged` handler and updating source manually is not required so i would remove that code.

---

If you do not explicitly set a mode on a binding the default will be used, from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx):

> **Default:** Uses the default [Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode.aspx) value of the binding target. The default value varies for each dependency property. In general, user-editable control properties, such as those of text boxes and check boxes, default to two-way bindings, whereas most other properties default to one-way bindings. A programmatic way to determine whether a dependency property binds one-way or two-way by default is to get the property metadata of the property using [GetMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.getmetadata.aspx) and then check the Boolean value of the [BindsTwoWayByDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.bindstwowaybydefault.aspx) property.

Comment: Nice one! Would be more than +1 if I could!  Had a custom user control with properties binding in to sub controls properties but not passing values back to the presenters.  Was looking at all sorts of stuff.  Hate how many magic flags there are in wpf but its great when it works!

Comment: Glad it helped, and yes, there is a lot to know but it is indeed a nice framework if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote: "Remember: I need a TwoWay binding", so:

```
<local:TextBoxEx MyProperty="{Binding Bar, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```