Weird behavior with re-usable control and DependencyProperty
I'm trying to make a small POC of a re-usable control but i'm experiencing weird behavior that I can't for the love of god figure out why.
So I'm hoping anyone here can shed some light onto this.
I'm trying to make a re-usable numeric input, with +/- buttons and configurable min/max values.
If the min/max is set and the user enters a value that is greater or smaller, I need the control to update the bound property to either the min or max allowed value.
It all works fine when manually inputting the value, but it doesn't work whenever the bound property is being set through code (e.g. on button click in the main viewmodel)
This the my output i'm gettin when manually filling out a value that's too large:
Setting BindThis to 105
BindThis set to 105
UC OnPropertyChanged: 25 -> 105
UC forcing min/max value: 100)
Setting BindThis to 100
BindThis set to 100
UC OnPropertyChanged: 105 -> 100

And this is what I get when I set BindThis to a value on button click:
Setting BindThis to 1000,2345678
UC OnPropertyChanged: 100 -> 1000,2345678
UC forcing min/max value: 100)
UC OnPropertyChanged: 1000,2345678 -> 100
BindThis set to 1000,2345678

Notice how the usercontrol's DependencyProperty stuff is being called while the property on the viewmodel is being set vs it all being done after the viewmodel's property been set when manually filling out the value.
Note that i'm using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm and the app is running under .NET 8:
<PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.3.2" />
Although I doubt that this has any effect on what I'm experiencing.
Given the following UserControl:
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             x:Name="MyControl">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyControl}">
        <Button Command="{Binding Decrease}" Content="-" />
        <TextBox Width="300" Text="{Binding Value}" />
        <Button Command="{Binding Increase}" Content="+" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            _increaseCommand = new RelayCommand(OnIncrease, CanIncrease);
            _decreaseCommand = new RelayCommand(OnDecrease, CanDecrease);

            InitializeComponent(); 
            
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Value), typeof(double?), typeof(UserControl1), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, ValueProperty_OnPropertyChanged));

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267840/dependency-property-updating-the-source
        private static void ValueProperty_OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"UC OnPropertyChanged: {e.OldValue} -> {e.NewValue}");
            UserControl1 instance = (UserControl1)d;
            double? newValue = (double?)e.NewValue;
            double? result = newValue;
            
            if(newValue != null)
            {
                if(newValue < instance.Min)
                {
                    result = instance.Min;
                }
                else if(newValue > instance.Max)
                {
                    result = instance.Max;
                }
            }

            if(newValue != result)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"UC forcing min/max value: {result})");
                d.SetCurrentValue(ValueProperty, result);
            }

            instance.Increase.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
            instance.Decrease.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
        }

        public double? Value
        {
            get => (double?)GetValue(ValueProperty);
            set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }

        public double Min { get; set; }
        public double Max { get; set; }

        private RelayCommand _increaseCommand;
        public RelayCommand Increase => _increaseCommand;
        
        private RelayCommand _decreaseCommand;
        public RelayCommand Decrease => _decreaseCommand;

        private bool CanDecrease() => Value - 1 >= Min;
        private void OnDecrease() => Value -= 1;

        private bool CanIncrease() => Value + 1 <= Max;
        private void OnIncrease() => Value += 1;
    }
}

Which is being used as such:
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding BindThis}" />
        <local:UserControl1 Value="{Binding BindThis, Mode=TwoWay}" Min="-100" Max="100" />
        <Button Command="{Binding ButtonClick}" Content="Over max" />
        <Button Command="{Binding ButtonMinClick}" Content="Below min" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private double? _value;
        public double? BindThis
        {
            get => _value;
            set
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Setting BindThis to {value}");
                SetProperty(ref _value, value);
                Debug.WriteLine($"BindThis set to {_value}");
            }
        }
        private void OnButtonMinClick() => BindThis = -1000.12345;

        private void OnButtonClick() => BindThis = 1000.2345678;

        private RelayCommand _btnClick;
        public ICommand ButtonClick => _btnClick;

        private RelayCommand _btnMinClick;
        public ICommand ButtonMinClick => _btnMinClick;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            _btnClick = new RelayCommand(OnButtonClick);
            _btnMinClick = new RelayCommand(OnButtonMinClick);
        }
    }
}

Update 1:
As suggested in the comments, I should be using the CoarceValueCallback and don't use SetCurrentValue in the OnPropertyChanged.
However, this results in the same behavior all over the line. The wrong value is being stored in the property on the view model, while the limited value is shown in the textbox.
These are the changes:
 public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
     nameof(Value), typeof(double?), typeof(UserControl1), 
     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, ValueProperty_OnPropertyChanged, ValueProperty_OnCoarceValue));

 private static object ValueProperty_OnCoarceValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
 {
     UserControl1 instance = (UserControl1)d;
     double? newValue = (double?)baseValue;
     double? result = newValue;

     if (newValue != null)
     {
         if (newValue < instance.Min)
         {
             result = instance.Min;
         }
         else if (newValue > instance.Max)
         {
             result = instance.Max;
         }
     }

     return result;
 }

 // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267840/dependency-property-updating-the-source
 // https://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html
 private static void ValueProperty_OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     //Debug.WriteLine($"UC OnPropertyChanged: {e.OldValue} -> {e.NewValue}");
     UserControl1 instance = (UserControl1)d;
     //double? newValue = (double?)e.NewValue;
     //double? result = newValue;
    
     //if(newValue != null)
     //{
     //    if(newValue < instance.Min)
     //    {
     //        result = instance.Min;
     //    }
     //    else if(newValue > instance.Max)
     //    {
     //        result = instance.Max;
     //    }
     //}

     //if(newValue != result)
     //{
     //    Debug.WriteLine($"UC forcing min/max value: {result})");
     //    d.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => d.SetCurrentValue(ValueProperty, result));
     //}

     instance.Increase.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
     instance.Decrease.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
 }


Hm, when I wrap the d.setCurrentValue(ValueProperty, result); in the ValueProperty_OnPropertyChanged callback inside a d.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke call, it does seem to work:
d.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => d.SetCurrentValue(ValueProperty, result));
But i'm not sure this is the way to go...

Calling SetCurrentValue in a PropertyChangedCallback is the wrong approach. Use a CoerceValueCallback.

@Clemens alright, i'll give that a go but I've already tried using the coarce callback.
I'd simply need to return the min/max value right, instead of using SetCurrentValue?

The callback returns the coerced value, Math.Min(Max, Math.Max(Min, value))

@Clemens so, with the CoarcedValue callback returning the either the min or max or value to be set, I have same behavior on manual input as with the value being set in code:
The viewmodel is updated with the value I entered (e.g. 200), but the input box shows 100

@Clemens I've updated the post with a code snippet of what i've changed :)

Value coercion only affects the value of the dependency property, but not the value of the source property of a potential binding of the dependency property. IMO your implementation with a view model is a bad idea in the first place. Increasing and decreasing logic should be implemented in the control. Simply derive your control from RangeBase.

For reference see also this and this.

@Clemens thanks, i'll have a look at the RangeBase.
I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "Increasing and decreasing logic should be implemented in the control"?
That's exactly what I've done? If you are referring to the over max / below min buttons, those are just a quick way to illustrate the value of the property that was bound to being set through code.
This could just as well happen after an API call has been made and the value of the property updated with something returned by the API, or some algorithm doing some calculations

I advise you to use Custom Control derived from RageBase or Slider instead of UserControl

WPF's default slider has all the functionalites you want. What you need to do is to create a custom Style for it.

I appreciate the inputs, but it's starting to feel y'all are focusing too much on the behavior with the min/max thing, whereas the actual issue lies with the DependencyProperty not setting the bound property again.
I just tried it with the vanilla Slider and the behavior is exactly the same. If i set the value on the viewmodel, it stays on the value I set it and the slider moves to the outer edge.

First we need to get the BindingExpression from ValueProperty so that we can update the source
    public UserControl1()
    {
        _increaseCommand = new RelayCommand(OnIncrease, CanIncrease);
        _decreaseCommand = new RelayCommand(OnDecrease, CanDecrease);

        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += UserControl1_Loaded;
    }

    private void UserControl1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _valueBindingExpression = GetBindingExpression(ValueProperty);
    }

And this is the magic line which saves most of the days
 await Task.Yield();

Complete method:
        private async static void ValueProperty_OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"UC OnPropertyChanged: {e.OldValue} -> {e.NewValue}");
            UserControl1 instance = (UserControl1)d;
            double? newValue = (double?)e.NewValue;
            double? result = newValue;

            if (newValue != null)
            {
                if (newValue < instance.Min)
                {
                    result = instance.Min;
                }
                else if (newValue > instance.Max)
                {
                    result = instance.Max;
                }
            }

            if (newValue != result)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"UC forcing min/max value: {result})");
                d.SetCurrentValue(ValueProperty, result);
                await Task.Yield();
                instance._valueBindingExpression?.UpdateSource();
            }
     
            instance.Increase.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
            instance.Decrease.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    

